# How to deploy Microsoft PowerApps using Intune?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, intune

I am having a requirement where we have to create SharePoint lists and run / create **PowerApps** from SharePoint lists and finally deploy them using **Intune**.
I got clarity till running and configuring PowerApps but how can I deploy PowerApps for iOS using Intune? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if I understand your question right, but basically I would assume you just have to deploy the IOS standard MS Powerapp app with Intune from the apple store. Once done have the users use their O365 login to access the powerapp app on their IOS devices,so they can use their assigned powerapps.

You have to assign/deploy the needed Powerapps in the Powerapps designer interface to the O365 users upfront).

I believe the link below explains the procedure how to deploy a apple store app that is free of charge (like Powerapps is)...hope that helps?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/store-apps-ios

Comment: Thanks chris for the link, it is helpful